# css: работа с <input>, позиционирование и :after

Tags: html, css, css3, input, позиционирование

Создал небольшой демо-пример:

```css
.block {
  width: 80%;
  height: 30px;
  background: lime;
}

.block .edit {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.block .edit li {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 75px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: orange;
}

.block .edit li input[type='text'] {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.block .edit li input[type='text']:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class='block'>
  <ul class='edit'>
    <li><input type="text"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Возникло 3 вопроса:

1. почему поле для ввода текста по высоте не стало таким же, как родительские элементы (я же поставил `height: 100%`)
2. почему для `<input>` не отображается `:after`, когда для остальных отображается, как побороть эту проблему?
3. можно ли отрисовать дочерний `div`, которому задать только `border`, сделав `background: transparent` и сделать так, чтобы нажатие на этот элемент не обрабатывалось, а нажимались элементы ниже (и все с помощью css)

Comment: в общем напишите *{box-sizing:border-box;} https://jsfiddle.net/famdpuhy/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалось решить проблемы

3) решается использованием

```
pointer-events:             none;
```

2) размещением за `<input>` другого объекта, например `<label>` и отслеживанием

```
input[type = 'text'].focus + label:after {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Пропишите для input `box-sizing: border-box;`
2) Это особенность инпутов: они не поддерживают псевдоэлементы
3) К сожалению вопрос не понял

```css
.block {
  width: 80%;
  height: 30px;
  
  background: lime;
}

.block .edit {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  
  list-style-type: none;
}

.block .edit li {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  
  margin-left: 75px;
  padding: 0px;
  
  background: orange;
}

.block .edit li input[type = 'text'] {
  
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.block .edit li.txt {
    position: relative;
}
.block .edit li.txt::after {
  content: '';
  
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class = 'block'>
  <ul class = 'edit'>
    <li class='txt'><input type = "text"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: по 1 помогает `* {
  box-sizing:     border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:  border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:  border-box; 
}`, :) ваш ответ уже появился, так что не будут дописывать свой ответ, спасибо.

Comment: по 3) - имел в виду, как нарисовать такой `div`, который был бы полностью прозрачным (кроме границы) и при наведении на который или нажатии на который срабатывали бы `:hover`, `:active`, `:focus` элементов, которые находятся под этим `div`, но которые видно (из-за прозрачности)

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку Duoxx уже дал печальный ответ по п.2) хотелось бы перефразировать задачу:

Мне требовалось, чтобы нажав на `<input>` элемент изменились бы свойства (граница) его родителя - `<li>` элемента, при том что `<input>` занимает лишь часть места `<li>`

Я думал решить её в 2 этапа:
1) для `<input>`, фокус которого я могу отследить создать псевдоэлемент `:after`, который будет размером с `<li>` и располагаться точно там же где и `<li>`
2) сделать так, чтобы `:after` был прозрачным (кроме границы) и можно было бы работать с элементами (в частности с `<input>`), которые оказались под ним

Можно как то это сделать?
Т.е. по изменению дочернего элемента менять родительский, или создавать иллюзию такого изменения (потому что вроде как css не позволяет менять родителя в зависимости от состояния дочернего элемента)

P.S.

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

действительно решает проблему 1), но откуда она вообще взялась -размеры установлены, padding, margin, border вроде как не должны влиять (первые два нулевые, а граница всего 2 пикселя)